# azuredevops PublishBuildArtifacts@1 .artifactignore file never taken

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I added the file .artifactignore in the pipeline.yml space, also added a CopyFiles@2 task after seeing few raising similar issue , and proposing that  .artifactignore should be in the same directory as defined as target path of the publish pipelines artifact task (not only in the root of the repo like azure-pipelines.yml).

Answer (score 0):

> azuredevops PublishBuildArtifacts@1 .artifactignore file never taken

The `.artifactignore` is a text file that controls what files are uploaded when you publish either a Universal Package or a **Pipeline Artifact** instead of **build pipeline**.

That is the reason why it never taken for your `PublishBuildArtifacts` task, we should use it for the Publish Pipeline Artifacts task:

```
- publish: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/TestArtifactignore
  artifact: Test
```

You could check the official document [Use the .artifactignore file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/reference/artifactignore?view=azure-devops) for some more details.

And this file is typically checked into your version control repository **in the same directory from which you upload your artifacts**.

And there is a great blog to introduce in detail [how to use this file `.artifactignore`](https://www.jfe.cloud/control-pipeline-artifacts-with-artifactignore-file/).

Comment: so you mean I have to replace PublishBuildArtifacts@1 with PublishPipelineArtifact@1?

Comment: @user847236, Yes.